# Can't override default margin of h1 text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Despite doing:

```
top: 0%;
margin-top: 0%;
padding-top: 0%;
```

there's still a gap between the top of the header in `#txt` and `#outer` - why?

It looks like it's because the `<h1>` text has a default margin that I can't override?

***[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/80351/dryy2j31/)***

Comment: i dont see any space between txt and outer

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'space'? I don't see a space, just a div that is smaller than it's parent.

Comment: @vulpcod3z by that I mean that there's a gap between the top of the h1 text and the top of #outer.

Comment: Ohh I see. That's because the header has a default margin. When you add h1 { margin-top: 0px; } to your css the space will disappear.

Comment: You are removing the margin of `#txt`. What made you think this would also remove the margin of `h1`? And you should include a [mcve] in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add this to your CSS

```
#txt h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a height of 90% which makes the object not as high as the parent and is therefore unable to reach the bottom.

Changing the height to 100% will fix the problem.

Edit: 
If you want to move the space from the bottom of the div to the top you have to change `top: 0%` to `top: 10%`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've changed the jsfiddle to have `height: 100%` on #txt but I still see space between the top of the header text and the top of #outer?

Comment: I'm sorry but when I change the height to 100% everything becomes green what means that #txt is aligning #outer. Do I miss something or do you see something different?

Comment: You're right that #txt is aligned with #outer but why doesn't the header text sit right at the top too?

Comment: It looks like it's because the `<h1>` text has a default margin that I can't override? @Nath van Beelen

Comment: Accidentally put the comment under the wrong post. (The mobile app isn't thay easy to use I see). You can see my response under your question.

Answer (score 0):

You had set a fixed height for #txt, from what i understood, this is what you're looking for?
https://jsfiddle.net/dryy2j31/5/

```
#txt {
position: absolute;
background-color: green;
top: 0%;
margin-top: 0%;
padding-top: 0%;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: not quite. There's still a gap between the top of the header text and the top of #outer?

Comment: It looks like it's because the`<h1>` text has a default margin that I can't override? @user2267175

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle you are applying the `margin:0%;` to the `#txt` div, so no rules are being applied to the `<h1>`. You just need to add `#txt h1 { margin: 0;` see below.

```js
var outer = document.createElement("div");
outer.id = "outer";

 var txt = document.createElement("div");
         txt.id = "txt";
         txt.innerHTML = "<h1>Enter your email</h1> <p>We need your email to do stuff.</p>";
outer.appendChild(txt);

document.body.appendChild(outer);
```

```css
#outer {
background-color: yellow;
width: 530px;
height: 300px;
position: absolute;
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
top: 9.05%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#txt {
position: absolute;
background-color: green;
top: 0%;
margin-top: 0%;
padding-top: 0%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#txt h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```